# How to refer to variable in the same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to achieve something like below

```
Select 
A = [variable 1 in C] + [variable 2 in C], 
B = CASE 
      WHEN A >1 THEN 1
    END
From C
```

How do I refer to A which is defined in the same statement when defining B subsequently, please? Thank you!

FYI, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Which SQL engine do you use?

Comment: please share some sample input and desired output for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a `cross apply`:

```
SELECT foo.A 
   , CASE WHEN foo.A > 1 THEN 1 END as B
FROM C
    CROSS APPLY
(SELECT variable_1 + variable_2 AS A) foo;
```

This does work at a different order of operation though so there are potentially some performance implications, but I've yet to hit them in my day to day life.

Answer (score 1):

Some people use a *derived table*, which is a query in the From clause, given an alias.

An example based off your pseudocode:

```
SELECT A = dT.myval
      ,B = CASE WHEN dT.myval > 1 THEN 1 END
  FROM (
         Select myval = [variable 1 in C] + [variable 2 in C] 
           FROM C
       ) AS dT
```

The example above has a derived table with the alias "dT".  The values in dT are calculated first.  Subsequently the values in dT are passed to the receiving query.  I referenced the results in the receiving query using the alias dT.

A second way is to use declared parameters. You declare a parameter, and give it a value. You inspect that value in a subsequent query. That's not doing all the work in the same query, however it does query the results using the same Select clause.

Ex.

```
DECLARE @A int = (SELECT [variable 1 in C] + [variable 2 in C]
                    FROM C);
SELECT @A AS [A]
      ,B = CASE WHEN @A > 1 THEN 1 END
```